# IllegalArgumentException: When using array of Objects as the value of SCHEMA_SOURCE property , no two Schemas should share the same targetNamespace

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, xerces, jaxp

I am using JasperReport/ireport4,
I tried to generate a report as below

```
public void fillReport() throws ParseException, groovyjarjarcommonscli.ParseException, IOException {

    try {
        Driver monDriver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(monDriver);
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB","", "");
        Map mymap = new HashMap();
        mymap.put("Title", MyTitle);
        mymap.put("legend", legend);
        mymap.put("SQL", Query());
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        InputStream reportStream = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("C:/Documents and Settings/report2.jasper");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        facesContext.responseComplete();
        response.setContentType("C:/Documents and Settings/report2.pdf");
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, mymap, connection);
        connection.close();
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    } catch (JRException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

but an error occured.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  When using array of Objects as the value of SCHEMA_SOURCE property , no two Schemas should share the same targetNamespace. 
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.processJAXPSchemaSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1647)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:241)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:228)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:216)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:170)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:154)
    at DAOKPI.Bean.fillReport(Bean.java:1139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:737)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:228)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    ... 34 more
```

here are my libraries

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To anyone using maven encountering this error:

Find out which one of your dependencies has a dependency on `xercesImpl.jar` and add an exclusion to the given dependency in your POM like so:

```xml
<dependency>
    ...
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

In my case, the troublemaker dependency was `jts`, so this is what my dependency declaration now looks like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

If you are using m2eclipse, you can find which dependency imports `xercesImpl.jar` on the *Dependency Hierarchy* tab of the POM editor.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. Mine it was net.sf.jmimemagic dependancy

Answer (score 0):

Do you have xerces.jar in your classpath? Because JasperReports has one already and if you have an older version then there might be conflicts. If so then try using only the one provided by JR.

Comment: ,hello, I have downloaded JasperReport4.0 ,their is no xerces.jar but what I found is xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar!

Comment: could you post all the libraries you're using in your project? It's for sure a problem with having one library in different versions or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

add this dependency using maven. it will solve the problem.