# Xerces XML parsing issue: 'No two Schemas should share the same targetNamespace'. How to fix it?

Tags: java, namespaces, weblogic, xerces, weld

I am trying to get a web application to run on a weblogic server, but it throws an exception telling that there were more than one xml file using the same namespace. I've searched all XML's and I couldn't find any!

It throws the exception that follows:

```
<01/09/2014 16h58min32s BRT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton not set for STATIC_INSTANCE => [].
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton not set for STATIC_INSTANCE => []
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.RegistrySingletonProvider$RegistrySingleton.get(RegistrySingletonProvider.java:28)
at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:55)
at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI.<init>(SimpleCDI.java:77)
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.StaticWeldProvider$EnhancedCDI.<init>(StaticWeldProvider.java:27)
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.StaticWeldProvider$EnhancedCDI.<init>(StaticWeldProvider.java:27)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<01/09/2014 16h58min33s BRT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  When using array of Objects as the value of SCHEMA_SOURCE property , no two Schemas should share the same targetNamespace. .
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  When using array of Objects as the value of SCHEMA_SOURCE property , no two Schemas should share the same targetNamespace. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.processJAXPSchemaSource(XMLSchemaLoader.java:839)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:605)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2453)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1772)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace"
```

Comment: Sounds like a classpath issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213219/error-with-display-a-report-on-the-browser-using-jsf http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/532845/getting-error-upgrading-371-version

Comment: Yeah... I also think it is... but I dont have a xerces lib in the project... I tried adding and removing it... and nothing works. I also tried to use xalan... nothing happens... don't matter what I do... the application doesnt works at weblogic server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem happened due to a weblogic 10 incompatibility with weld. To resolve it I would have to change things into weblogic jars, so It couldnt work with that version of weblogic at all. I changed to a later version and weblogic and it worked fine.